# src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'at:AutomaticTask' to a(n) 'element declaration' component

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I read some similar questions posted but still couldn't resolve my issue.

```
src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'at:AutomaticTask' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.
```

I have main.xsd import task.xsd like bellow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:at="http://my.sample.com/bpmn" targetNamespace="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <xs:import namespace="http://my.sample.com/bpmn" schemaLocation="task.xsd" />
   <xs:element name="definitions">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="userTask">
               <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                     <xs:element name="extensionElements">
                        <xs:complexType>
                           <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                              <xs:element ref="at:AutomaticTask" />
                           </xs:choice>
                        </xs:complexType>
                     </xs:element>
                  </xs:choice>
                  <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                  <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
               </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And my task.xsd is as follow. Both xsd files in same folder under test/resoures and I am writing unit test.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://my.sample.com/bpmn"
           xmlns="http://my.sample.com/bpmn"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="AutomaticTask">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

here is the xml to validate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:at="http://my.sample.com/bpmn">
    <userTask id="123xb" name="task1">
        <extensionElements>
            <at:automaticTask name="myTask" id="0318ba00" />
        </extensionElements>
        <incoming>SequenceFlow_1x3hpv4</incoming>
        <outgoing>SequenceFlow_02ko1r6</outgoing>
    </userTask>
</definitions>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `xs:schema/@targetNamespace` in the imported XSD (`task.xsd`) from `my.sample.com/bpmn` to `http://my.sample.com/bpmn` to match the value given by the `xmlns:at` namespace prefix declaration and `xs:import/@namespace` in the importing XSD (`main.xsd`).

Here are your XSDs repaired to eliminate the error:

### main.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"
           xmlns:at="http://my.sample.com/bpmn"
           targetNamespace="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:import namespace="http://my.sample.com/bpmn" schemaLocation="task.xsd" />
  <xs:element name="definitions">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="userTask">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:element name="extensionElements">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element ref="at:AutomaticTask" />
                  </xs:choice>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

### task.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://my.sample.com/bpmn"
           xmlns="http://my.sample.com.com/bpmn"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="AutomaticTask">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

---

**Update:**

The following repaired XML file is now valid per the above XSDs:

### main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"
             xmlns:at="http://my.sample.com/bpmn"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL 
                                 try.xsd">
    <userTask id="123xb" name="task1">
        <extensionElements>
            <at:AutomaticTask name="myTask" id="0318ba00" />
        </extensionElements>
        <!-- incoming and outgoing are not defined in your XSD:
        <incoming>SequenceFlow_1x3hpv4</incoming>
        <outgoing>SequenceFlow_02ko1r6</outgoing>
        -->
    </userTask>
</definitions>
```

Comment: Sorry. That was type error. I corrected the original question.

Comment: There was more than one mistake, and I'm sorry that I didn't get them all for you the first time.  I've updated the answer to eliminate the second and final mistake ( typo: `.com.com` should be `.com`) and verified that the error is eliminated.

Comment: I've added the complete, corrected XSDs to the answer.

Comment: BTW, you can simplify by eliminating the `xs:choice` elements that have only a single child element, but I left it intact in case it's part of your original, real XSD to show that the reference problem has been resolved regardless of that nit.

Comment: those errors you mentioned are all type errors introduced during writing the question. My original version has the same uri. Just couldn't figure out what else could be wrong. For xs:choice, I have more elements under there. But thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: My issue isn't resolved yet. I verified the name spaces are correct in my xsds. I added my test xml file.

Comment: You had **more typos** and namespace agreement issues.  I've fixed them for you once more.  This is the last post I'll be making on this topic.  I hope you've gotten enough help here to be able to resolve any additional problems on your own.  Good luck.